# Gnome-session not installing because of gnome-session-common even though it is installed and updated

Tags: gnome, package-management, gnome-session, customizer

So anyway after I figured out how to install customizer, I began testing with chroot (or the terminal feature to install packages and customize changes)

gnome-session says that gnome-session-common is not installed and tries to install it,but it fails,thus failing the whole gnome-session installation, So i try to install it manually, but it says it is installed and updated

Anyway the ISO is Ubuntu 17.10.1. Here is what happened in the terminal:

```
/# sudo apt install gnome-session

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree      

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gnome-session : Depends: gnome-session-common (= 3.26.1-0ubuntu5) but 3.26.1-0ubuntu6 is to be installed

Recommends: adwaita-icon-theme-full

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anyway to fix this, I am very frustrated because of this error

Comment: What was the last thing you installed (or failed to install) before this problem began?

Comment: I installed a icon theme from noobslab, Chromuim, and the gnome desktop themes

Comment: So you installed Gnome desktop themes (from where? what source?)...and then began having Gnome dependency errors? If so, have you tried the obvious solution?

Comment: it is gnome-desktop-themes because gnome-session requested i have it so i installed it, so what is the obvious solution ?

Comment: The obvious solution to try is uninstalling your non-Ubuntu version of gnome-desktop-themes, and (optionally) replacing it with the Ubuntu version. Two packages from from different sources may share a common *name*, but that does not mean they are compatible - they may have different *versions*, they may have entirely different *files*.

Comment: No need, As I posted this on reddit.com/r/linuxquestions and got it answered. Turns out it was a mistake in the sources.list file that i fixed and then it installed

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced the last string in `sources.list` with

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main universe restricted
```

and it fixed the problem.